# Red-Black Tree - Deletion method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures, red-black-tree

See original Red-Black Tree below:

```
         42B
       /    \
     10R     64B
    /  \     /  \
  7B   29B 50R  83R
  /
5R
```

I am having trouble when trying to the delete 29. Since trying to delete this node results in a double-black (let's call it DB) case and DB's far nephew (`5R`) node is a RED node, we should be able to solve this by simply swapping the colors of parent (`10R`) and sibling (`7B`) nodes, rotating DB's parent in DB's direction and coloring DB's nephew BLACK, so the result would be:

```
         42B
       /    \
     7R     64B
    /  \     /  \
  5B   10B 50R  83R
```

But instead I'm getting the following:

```
         42B
       /    \
     10B     64B
    /  \     /  \
  NIL   29B 50R  83R
```

See code below, `remove(value)` calls `removeBST(root,value)` that calls `fixDoubleBlack()` if needed.  Since it is a lengthy code, I've omitted the non-related part, but I've posted the code [here](https://repl.it/@ptorr/RB-Tree#index.js). I know this may take some time and it is a lot to ask so thanks a lot to anyone who bothers to take a look. I sure got a couple of years older trying to debug this.

```
class redBlackTree {
  constructor () {
    this.root = null;
  }
  ... ...
  
  // ------------- RED BLACK: NODE REMOVAL METHODS ------------->>
  remove(value) {
    let node = new Node(value); 

    if (this.root === null) { return; } 
    
    this.root = this.removeBST(this.root, node);
  }

  removeBST (root, node) {//Binary Search Tree (BST) regular remove() method.
    if (root === null || node === null) { return null; } //Tree is either empty or node=null

    if (node.value === root.value) { //value to be removed was found
      if ((root.left === null) && (root.right === null)) { //node is a leaf node.
        if(root === this.root) { return null; } //node is root, just remove it.
        else if (root.color === 'RED') { return null; } //node is a leaf and is RED, just remove it.
        else { 
          //Node being removed (29) is a BLACK node w/ no children, fix double-black.

          this.fixDoubleBlack(root);
          root = null; 

          //calling inOrderTraversal() here shows the correct result.
        }
      } 
  
     }
    ... another cases ...
    else if (node.value < root.value) { root.left = this.removeBST(root.left, node); }
    else if (node.value > root.value) { root.right = this.removeBST(root.right, node); }

    return root; //I believe the problem may be in this return statement !!!
  }

  fixDoubleBlack(node) {
  
    if(node === this.root) { return; } 
    let sibling = this.getSibling(node);
    let parent = node.parent;

    if(!sibling) { this.fixDoubleBlack(parent); }
    else {
      if(sibling.color === 'RED') {... sibling is RED ... }
      else {//As sibling is BLACK, we have three cases that can be applied:
        if(this.anyRedChild(sibling)){//1-: sibling has at least one RED child
          if(this.isLeftChild(sibling)){//sibling is left child
            if(sibling.left && sibling.left.color === 'RED'){
              //DB's far nephew is RED:

              this.colorSwap(parent,sibling); 
              this.colorSwitch(sibling.left); 
              this.rightRotation(parent);

              parent.right = null;

              //calling inOrderTraversal() here shows the correct result.
            }
            else { ... }
          }
          else { ... }
        } 
        else { ... }
      }
    }
  }

  // ---------------------- SUPPORT METHODS -------------------->>
  colorSwitch(node){ ... inverts the color of the node ...}
  colorSwap(node1, node2){ ... swaps the colors of the nodes ...}
  getSibling(node){ ... returns the sibling of the node passed as argument ...}
  isLeftChild(node){... returns a boolean if the node is a left child ... }
  anyRedChild(node){... returns a boolean if the node has a RED child ...}

  // --------------------- ROTATION METHODS -------------------->> 
  rightRotation(node) {//LL condition --> Right Rotation
    let tempNode = node.left;
    node.left = tempNode.right;

    //Update parent reference in case of temp node having a right subtree:
    if(node.left !== null) { node.left.parent = node; }

    //Update temp node parent to be node's parent:
    tempNode.parent = node.parent;

    //Update parent references for rotated node:
    if(node.parent === null) { this.root = tempNode; }
    else if(node === node.parent.left) { node.parent.left = tempNode; }
    else { node.parent.right = tempNode; } 

    tempNode.right = node;
    node.parent = tempNode;
  }
  ...

  // --------------------- TRAVERSAL METHODS ------------------->>
  levelOrderTraversal() {//1st level --> 2nd level --> 3rd level ...
    let queue = [];
    if (this.root !== null) {
      queue.push(this.root);
      while (queue.length > 0) {
        let node = queue.shift();
        console.log(node.value);
        if (node.left !== null) {
          queue.push(node.left);
        }
        if (node.right !== null) {
          queue.push(node.right);
        }
      }
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
let rbTree = new redBlackTree();

rbTree.insert(42); rbTree.insert(10);  rbTree.insert(64);
rbTree.insert(7);  rbTree.insert(29);  rbTree.insert(50);
rbTree.insert(83); rbTree.insert(5); 

rbTree.remove(29); 

rbTree.levelOrderTraversal();
```

As mentioned above, calling `levelOrderTraversal()` after the `fixDoubleBlack()` call shows the correct result, so I'm left with the thought that it might be the `removeBST` `return` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next try. :)

Do you need to return anything by `removeBST`? I think you don't, because you do modify the corresponding nodes when you do the rotations and other smart things.

So instead of `root.left = this.removeBST(root.left, node)`, just write `this.removeBST(root.left, node)` and do the same with the right child. Also, just call `this.removeBST` in `remove`, but don't reassign `this.root`. It seems to work on the example, but I might be missing some other case where you really need it. ([code](https://repl.it/repls/HollowAlertNetworking#index.js))

Comment: Yep, you were totally right, the `return` madness was just adding confusion to an already confusing code. After making the changes you suggested and a few more tweaks to update the references, it seems we got ourselves a fully functional Red-Black tree. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that `removeBST(root, node)` always returns `root` (possibly with different children). If you do a rotation, you should return the new root of the subtree.

Where does it cause problems in your example?

You call `root.left = this.removeBST(root.left, node);` with `root.value = 42, root.left.value = 10.` You do what you need to do in the left subtree, but then assign the node with value `10` as the left child of `42`.

You also call `root.right = this.removeBST(root.right, node);` when `root.value` is `10` and `root.right.value` is `29`. You do the rotation correctly (if you look at `this.root` just after the rotation, it looks good), but then you return the node with value `29` and assign it to `root.right`!

Comment: Yes, you are right, the issue is within this return logic. I've tried updating `root` soon after the call for `fixDoubleBlack(root)` to return a different node, but to no success. I might go back and start this deletion logic from scratch once I find the courage. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, sorry, I must have skipped your last few lines after the code snippet, where you write exactly this. I guess I just started to look at the code and forgot to read further.